# に[配慮]{はいりょ} vs. を[配慮]{はいりょ}

Tags: grammar

I want to know if there is any difference between `に` and `を` when used with `配慮する`.

Example sentences:

> [環境]{かんきょう}**に**配慮した家
>
> 環境**を**配慮した家
>
> [相手]{あいて}の[立場]{たちば}**に**配慮する
>
> 相手の立場**を**配慮する

Are they interchangeable? Does the meaning change at all?
(Googling gives many hits for both, but I feel like `を` should be not used in these situations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you. Using を sounds ungrammatical. With 考慮, を should be used, and I think the writer of を配慮 got mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, google gives [1,870,000 hits](https://www.google.co.jp/#hl=ja&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%82%92%E9%85%8D%E6%85%AE%22&oq=%22%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%82%92%E9%85%8D%E6%85%AE%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...700.8306.1.8472.34.24.10.0.0.8.672.5050.0j19j2j1j0j2.24.0...0.0.hVFX62l3cxQ&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2c69993cc4303b8a&biw=1280&bih=907), which is quite significant. I know google can't always be trusted though.

Comment: @JesseGood Your link only gives 462 hits, not 1,870,000. https://www.google.co.jp/#q=%22%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%82%92%E9%85%8D%E6%85%AE%22&hl=ja&prmd=imvns&ei=TVjZT9TbDIeZiQemybGSAw&start=455&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1c31c584c5bb3106&biw=1366&bih=678

Answer (score 0):

「に配慮する」はtake care of　（自動詞）
「を配慮する」はcare （他動詞）

Comment: Are you saying that the sentence with を is not ungrammatical as the other answer suggests?