# Are there any common grammatical errors made by native Japanese speakers?

Tags: grammar

Sorry if this is a really open-ended question, but one thing occurred to me when I was asking a prior question here; are there any particular grammatical errors frequently made by *native* Japanese speakers?

For example, in English there are quite a few obvious mistakes that native speakers make - `your` vs. `you're` and `me and Sally went...` rather than `Sally and I went...` and often non-native speakers of English are better at distinguishing between them than native speakers.

Is there any such Japanese grammar that is commonly used incorrectly by native speakers?

I am more interested in common mistakes than obscure mistakes; mistakes where one would think that a native speaker should know better.

Comment: 「通り」should be written 「とおり」 in hiragana but I've seen many people write it as 「とうり」。 (Wait, is this a "grammatical" error?) Maybe「ら抜き言葉」is seen as a grammatical error (but I'm not sure). And many people say/write "~~たり~~する" but I learned at school that we should say/write "~~たり~~たりする"

Comment: Now I remembered we often say 「すごい寒い~!」「すごい嬉しい~!」「すごい+ an adjective」. I think we use すごく when we write formally though.

Comment: Maybe this should be community wiki? There also seems to be some confusion between the imperative of ichidan verbs and godan verbs ending in -iru and -eru. Is it しゃべれ or しゃべろ, みれ or みろ etc. There might be some dialectal influence on this too, not sure.

Comment: Interesting question. Try not confuse evolution of modern Japanese vs real grammar mistake.

Comment: I see books about this in bookstores here all the time. Maybe I should go pick one up...

Comment: Those aren't really good examples of "grammatical errors". "You're"/"your" is just spelling and most of the time its not even a legitimate mistake. Also mistakes in text/print are usually not mistakes of language but mistakes of typing or editing and whatnot. I would also take special heed to oldergod's comment on the distinction between "semi-tolerated emergent conventions" and a true linguistic error. The latter are by far much more interesting, especially when the culprit is perverse enough to violate a linguistic universal, and not just a language particular.

Comment: "me and Sally" is correct English, documented back hundreds of years. Usually, an error in the use of "me" and "I" is the result of a learned hypercorrection.

Answer (score 3):

If some construct is common among native speakers, is it a grammatical error, or an artifact of a shared dialect? It's an error in the prescriptive sense, in that it is contrary to some preferred dialect that is promulgated by schools and institutions.

Here is an example: using 全然 (zen zen, *[not] at all*), in the positive sense (*totally*).

"昨日,　全然楽しかったよ！”　(Kinou, zen zen tanoshikatta, yo! *Yesterday was totally fun!*)

Comment: Oh yes~~ I say 全然いいよ very often, knowing it's wrong! >▽<

Comment: @chocolate: Actually, that is a common misconception, [see here](http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXBZO37057770W1A201C1000000/).

Comment: @JesseGood Ewww so 全然+肯定文 is not incorrect? I didn't know that~ 遠慮なく使おう・・・w

Comment: Well, the misconception is that some usage which a community of speakers accept and use can be "wrong".

Comment: Actually since 2012 I learned that the positive 全然 may be historically right; the banishment is a prescriptivist hyper-correction, or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it is common, but I asked a [question once](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/%E3%81%AB%E9%85%8D%E6%85%AE%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%82%8A%E3%82%87-vs-%E3%82%92%E9%85%8D%E6%85%AE%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%82%8A%E3%82%87) about something I often saw: (I think these types of mistakes are common though when you mix up to words)

> 環境を配慮した家 <-- Should be に not を

Using たり only once ([reference](http://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/gimon/154.html)):

> ×本を読んだり、手紙を書く暇もありません。
>
> →○本を読んだり、手紙を書いたりする暇もありません。

Using two words that mean the same thing in a row (very common):

> まず初めに
>
> 今現在

Using 申し訳ない as 申し訳ありません or 申し訳ございません. Technically 申し訳ない is a 形容詞.

なので at the beginning of a sentence.

すいません instead of すみません (perhaps more of a spoken thing).

こんにちわ instead of こんにちは

Comment: That point about 申し訳ない is interesting. So is 申し訳ありません prescriptively incorrect? I could have sworn we had been taught it.

Comment: @jogloran: Prescriptively, yes. [Here is a link](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q106772260) in Japanese talking about it. However, it is so common, taking a descriptive approach might be better (still up for debate).

Comment: Thanks for that. As the link says, 申し訳ありません is incorrect in the same way that 危ありません is incorrect, but the descriptive tendency is probably because 申し訳 also occurs as a standalone noun while 危(あぶ) does not. Also, I would never have thought 申し訳のう to be the correct combining form.

Comment: Why is `なので` at the beginning of a sentence incorrect?

Comment: @istrasci: The `な` of なので is the same one as seen in `簡単な問題`, so grammatically it is used to connect 形容詞, etc. (called 連体形) to other words. When な is used at the beginning of a sentence, its incorrect because it isn't attached to anything.

Comment: @JesseGood: I thought it was just an implied `（それ）なので`, where `それ` is the entire previous sentence/paragraph that is being used as the reasoning, while being intentionally omitted.

Comment: @istrasci: Yes, that is the case when spoken, but omitting the `それ` in writing is not acceptable. Also, there is generally a better way to phrase the sentence in most cases, for example `私最近とても忙しいんです。なので、ちょっと予定が立てにくいんです` would be better as `私最近とても忙しいので、ちょっと予定が立てにくいんです`. ([example taken from here](http://www.tv-asahi.co.jp/announcer/nihongo/labo/lab_012/body.html))

Comment: (Late to the party, but hey...) @jogloran, 申し訳のう is the 連用形 in certain dialects of southwestern Japanese. This is the same ウ音便 that we see in words like おはよう (from はやく → はやう → はよう), or おめでとう (from めでたく → めでたう → めでとう).  So the 終止形・連体形 form for 申し訳のう is 申し訳ない.  In Kantō speech, the 連用形 would be 申し訳なく.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about native speakers, but I know that a commonly made mistake is to use a grammatical structure such as ~と思う without the necessary だ if preceded by a noun or な adjective.